# Creating a database schema that allows the admin to set 1 or many access to user

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-schema

I am planning to create a database that allows many vehicles of the user to access different gates depending on their privileges.

For example, I have **`5 gates`** namely `Gate 1`, `Gate 2`, `Gate 3`, `Gate 4`, `Gate 5` and I have **`3 users`** namely `User 1`, `User 2` and `user 3`.

**Scenario 1:** User 1 is the owner of the city so this user should have access to all 5 gates.

**Scenario 2:** User 2 is just a visitor so this user shouldn't have access to all 5 gates.

**Scenario 3:** User 3 is one of the residents of this city, but gates 4 and 5 only allows the owners of the city, this user should only access gates 1-3 since this user is not the owner.

**Scenario 4:** User 3 is one the residents of this city and since user 1 is the owner he allows user 3 to access also gate 4 for them have a dinner this evening and ask the administrator that tomorrow he should remove the gate 4 privilege of this user

Based on my planning this database schema should be something like this

**`vehicle_info table`**             **`access_type table`**

1. vehicle_id                         1. access_id
2. plate_num                         2. name
3. access_type
4. validity - the validity of the access type (date only)

Then I will connect `vehicle_info.access_type` to `access_type.name`. But what if the city builds another gate namely `gate 6` and also want it to add to the access_type?

Comment: If each city can have more than one gate, that is a 1:M relationship.  Then each person can have access by whether there is a relationship with a particular gate.  Adding a new gate is just a matter of adding a new row in the CityGate table then enable a user by adding a row in the USerCityGate table.

Comment: @Plutonix, ah yes. So I also need to create a table for each gate right?

Comment: You don't create a table for each gate.  You create a table of gates, where each record represents a gate.  If ever you add a thing to a system, that should only require you to add a row to your database.  If it requires you to add a table then your design is wrong.  A table represents a type of thing.  In simple terms, you could create a `User` table, a `Gate` table and then a `UserGate` table to represent each gate that each user has access to.  A user can only access a gate if there exists a `UserGate` record for that combination.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, ah yes you are right about that. But I'm wondering how do I make an `access_type` table that links to the `UserGate table`? Do I need to create a title for each access type like `owner only` and it is linked to `gate 4 and 5`, then `residents only` that `allows gate 1 to 3`? Please add an answer.

Comment: Is MySQL a requirement here? Other dbs a possibility?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan yes Sir. MySQL is the requiremet here. Thanks.